# Flex LiveCycle DataServices issues with Flexicious datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am using flexicious datagrid to display realtime data using Flex livecycle dataservices.
The Flexious grid is able to show the data that is pulled from the server initially but when the server is pushing updates back to the client, the grid is not showing the new records.

The same data shows up realtime when i replace the flexicious grid with a normal datagrid or advanced datagrid.

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Rajeev

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out this issue myself.

There is a property on the `ExtendedGrid` i.e. `filterPageSortMode` which default points to value client. To make the above case working I change it to server and it worked.

But this came up with another issue. Now I am no more able to do sort on the data in the grid because with `filterPageSortMode="server"` the grid assumes that the sorting logic is coming from server instead of using grid inbuilt sorting capabilities.

It would be great to know how we can keep using the grid's sort functionality by keeping `filterPageSortMode="server"`.

Thanks,
Rajeev